# How to add button click effect in alertdialog buttons in android

Tags: android, animation, android-alertdialog

I am having an alertdialog box  in which i have customized the the background for the alertdialog buttons.In that i would like to add an effect for the button click can anyone tell me how can i add an button click effect for the alertdialog as well how could i change the size of the button in alert dialog.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            NewDaybook_Activity.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(R.string.clickyestoexit)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(a);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    Button nbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    Button pbutton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    pbutton.setPadding(0, 10, 10, 0);
    pbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

[image]

Comment: Onclick is already added for both buttons what do you want to do please explain

Comment: @santoshkumar when we click the button i want to show ripple effect for the button

Answer (score 0):

Ripple effect is already present above Kitkat Versions,
For pre kitkat version use this [library](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) for ripple effect.

Comment: Even though this answer is correct, this is not why he doesn't have the ripple effect on the buttons of his dialog. To get the ripple effect on a dialog, a custom layout should be used.